# How to select and run model from dash dropdown menu and update confusion matrix figure?

Tags: python, machine-learning, model, plotly-dash

I am building an ML prediction dash app based on this [breast cancer dataset](https://www.kaggle.com/merishnasuwal/breast-cancer-prediction-dataset).

From a dropdown menu, I want to be able to select one of my models, run the fitting, and return an updated confusion matrix (heatmap).

I plan to extend the script to tables, roc-curves, learning-curves, etc. (i.e., a [multi output callback](https://community.plot.ly/t/multiple-outputs-in-dash-now-available/19437) ) - but first I want this part to work, before implementing the other elements.

I have tried different things.

For instance, before the current code (below), I tried calling the model from the dropdown menu directly and then doing all the cm calculations inside the callback results in a ***AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'fit'***:

```
@app.callback(Output('conf_matrix', 'figure'), [Input('dropdown-5', 'value')])
def update_cm_matix(model):
    class_names=[0,1]
    fitModel = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = fitModel.predict(X_test)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    return {'data': [go.Heatmap(x=class_names, y=class_names, z=cm, showscale=True, colorscale='blues')],
            'layout': dict(width=350, height=280, margin={'t': 10},
                       xaxis=dict(title='Predicted class', tickvals=[0, 1]),
                       yaxis=dict(title='True class', tickvals=[0, 1], autorange='reversed'))}
```

(replacing the app.callback and function in the script below).

The current version I am struggling with is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
from sklearn.feature_selection import RFE
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

app = dash.Dash(__name__, external_stylesheets=[dbc.themes.BOOTSTRAP])
server = app.server

app.config.suppress_callback_exceptions = True

df = pd.read_csv("breast_cancer.csv")
y = np.array(df.diagnosis.tolist())
data = df.drop('diagnosis', 1)
X = np.array(data.values)

scaler = StandardScaler()
X = scaler.fit_transform(X)

random_state = 42
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=random_state)

# First model: logistic model + optimize hyperparameters
log = LogisticRegression(random_state=random_state)
param_grid = {'penalty': ['l2', 'l1'], 'C': [0.001, 0.01, 0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000]}
CV_log = GridSearchCV(estimator=log, param_grid=param_grid,, scoring='accuracy', verbose=1, n_jobs=-1)
CV_log.fit(X_train, y_train)
log_best_params = CV_log.best_params_
log_clf = LogisticRegression(C=log_best_params['C'], penalty=log_best_params['penalty'], random_state=random_state)

# Second model: logistic model with recursive features elimination (just for illustration purposes, other models will be included)
rfe_selector = RFE(log_clf)

# app layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        dcc.Dropdown(
            id='dropdown-5',
            options=[{'label': 'Logistic', 'value': 'log_clf'},
                     {'label': 'RFE', 'value': 'rfe_selector'}],
            value='log_clf',
            style={'width': '150px', 'height': '35px', 'fontSize': '10pt'}
        )], style={}),

    html.Div([
        dcc.Graph(id='conf_matrix')
    ])
])

# function to run selected model
def ClassTrainEval(model):
    fitModel = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = fitModel.predict(X_test)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    return fitModel, y_pred, y_score, cm

models = [log_clf, rfe_selector]
class_names = [0,1]

# dash callback
@app.callback(Output('conf_matrix', 'figure'), [Input('dropdown-5', 'value')])
def update_cm_matix(model):
    for model in models:
        ClassTrainEval(model)
    return {'data': [go.Heatmap(x=class_names, y=class_names, z=cm, showscale=True, colorscale='blues')],
            'layout': dict(width=350, height=280, margin={'t': 10},
                           xaxis=dict(title='Predicted class', tickvals=[0, 1]),
                           yaxis=dict(title='True class', tickvals=[0, 1], autorange='reversed'))}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Where I get an ***NameError: name 'cm' is not defined*** error.

I am not really sure how to move forward to get this to work - so I hope that someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are mutliple mistakes in you code. let's work out your two tries first.

```
dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown-5',
        options=[{'label': 'Logistic', 'value': 'log_clf'},
                 {'label': 'RFE', 'value': 'rfe_selector'}],
        value='log_clf',
        style={'width': '150px', 'height': '35px', 'fontSize': '10pt'}
    )], style={})
```

in your dropdown, the model is a String (`type('log_clf') == str`) so you cannot train it. you need to write the callback as follow:

```
models = {'Logistic':log_clf, 'RFE':rfe_selector}
""""i jumped some line of code"""
dcc.Dropdown(
        id='dropdown-5',
        options=[{'label': v, 'value': v} for v in ['Logistic','RFE']],
        value='Logistic',
        style={'width': '150px', 'height': '35px', 'fontSize': '10pt'}
    )
```

for the second try, you also need a line to adapt from the changes i made:

the error was : `NameError: name 'cm' is not defined error` (i assume it happened in the callback)  and is happening because you did not assigned the outputs of the function to variables:

the function was

```
# function to run selected model
def ClassTrainEval(model):
    fitModel = model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = fitModel.predict(X_test)
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    return fitModel, y_pred, y_score, cm #Note that y_score is never defined so you need to remove this
```

and then in the callback you have:

```
# dash callback
@app.callback(Output('conf_matrix', 'figure'), [Input('dropdown-5', 'value')])
def update_cm_matix(model):
    for model in models: #<-------No loop needed
        ClassTrainEval(model) #<-------Here You need to assigne the output
    return {'data': [go.Heatmap(x=class_names, y=class_names, z=cm, showscale=True, colorscale='blues')],
            'layout': dict(width=350, height=280, margin={'t': 10},
                           xaxis=dict(title='Predicted class', tickvals=[0, 1]),
                           yaxis=dict(title='True class', tickvals=[0, 1], autorange='reversed'))}
```

you may want to write:

```
@app.callback(Output('conf_matrix', 'figure'), [Input('dropdown-5', 'value')])
def update_cm_matix(v):
    model = models[v]
    fitModel, y_pred, cm =  ClassTrainEval(model)
    return {'data': [go.Heatmap(x=class_names, y=class_names, z=cm, showscale=True, colorscale='blues')],
            'layout': dict(width=350, height=280, margin={'t': 10},
                           xaxis=dict(title='Predicted class', tickvals=[0, 1]),
                           yaxis=dict(title='True class', tickvals=[0, 1], autorange='reversed'))}
```

Comment: Thank you! Your explanation really helped me understand what is going on - and it works now. (I removed y_score - not y_pred from the return in ClassTrainEval).

Comment: yep indeed, wrong variable, i'll update for future users.